# Create hardlinks instead of copying files with rsync

Tags: command-line, find, rsync

The following command finds recursively all files containing `foo` (but not `bar`) and preserves the directory structure in the target directory, for example if I have `/path/to/2017/foo.ps` and `/path/to/2018/foo.pdf` it creates the subdirectories `2017` and `2018` under `~/path/to/dir/` containing `foo.ps` resp. `foo.pdf`.

```
find . -iname \*foo\*pdf -exec rsync -R --exclude='*bar*' {} ~/path/to/dir/ \;
```

What is the equivalent to this command such that I end up with hardlinks instead of copies?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since no one else did, to answer the title question, you can use `--link-dest`. Generally, if you want to sync `s/` to `d/` with rsync but using hardlinks instead of copies, you can do:

```
rsync -r --link-dest="$PWD/s/" s/ d/
```

As to your specific need, where you want to specify files and not whole directories, you can do:

```
find . \
  -iname \*foo\*pdf \
  -exec bash -c '
    rsync -R \
      --exclude="*bar*" \
      --link-dest="$PWD/$(dirname "$1")" \
      "$1" \
      ~/path/to/dir/
  ' sh {} \;
```

The reason why bash is introduced here is to be able to get the `dirname` of the filepath. `--link-dest` needs the directory and not the file itself. I also use `$PWD` because `--link-dest` is relative to the destination directory, not the current directory.

Comment: should be noted that this is a great way of hardlinking on newer MacOSes that produce warnings when using `cp -l`

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't look very much like a job for rsync. Rsync is mostly useful for recursive copies, but evidently you only intend to copy regular files. The only advantage of `rsync` over `cp` here is that it creates the parent directories as needed. You could do it with a small shell script calling `mkdir` instead.

```
find . -type f -iname '*foo*.pdf' ! -name '*bar*' \
       -exec sh -c 'mkdir -p "~/path/to/dir/${0%/*}" && cp "$0" ~/path/to/dir/"$0"' {} \;
```

- Add `-type f` to the `find` command to exclude non-regular files (e.g. directories). Use `-xtype f` to also process symbolic links to regular files.
- `! -name '*bar*'` is equivalent to the rsync `--exclude` option.
- `sh -c '…' {}` executes the shell script `…` with `$0` set to the file name found by `find`.
- `mkdir -p …` creates the target directory and any parent as necessary.

Here you can substitute `ln` for `cp` to create a hard link.

---

Alternatively you can use [zsh](https://www.slideshare.net/jaguardesignstudio/why-zsh-is-cooler-than-your-shell-16194692)'s [`zmv`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv) function. In zsh:

```
setopt extended_glob
autoload zmv
mkdir_ln () {
  mkdir -p -- $2:h
  ln -- $1 $2
}
zmv -p mkdir_ln '**/(#i)*foo*.pdf~**/*bar*' ~/path/to/dir/'$f'
```

- `zmv -p mkdir_ln PATTERN REPLACEMENT` calls `mkdir_ln FILENAME REPLACEMENT` for each `FILENAME` that matches `PATTERN`, with `$f` in `REPLACEMENT` replaced by `FILENAME`.
- `mkdir -p -- $2:h` creates the directory part of `$2` and any parent directory as needed.
- `**/…` matches files in subdirectories recursively.
- `(#i)` starts a case-insensitive match.
- `~**/*bar*` excludes files whose name contains `bar`.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for `pax`:

```
find . -iname '*foo*pdf' ! -name '*bar*' -print0 |
  pax -0rwl ~/path/to/dir/
```

If your `pax` doesn't support the non-standard `-0`, remove the `0` from `-print0` and `-0rwl` but beware that won't work properly if you have file paths that contain newline character.

If you don't have `pax` (POSIX, but not GNU), try replacing with `cpio -0pd` (GNU, but not POSIX).